# How to overlap table rows?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make the table rows to overlap each other, using only css and html?

Please help. The page is here, when the user choose conditional leave, they will prompt with different additional field(s) to fill up. But I just want to know if rows can be set to overlap so the table will not be too long.

http://www.tritech.com.sg/consultants/intranet/leave_application/leave_form/index.php

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you are trying to achieve, possibly including a jsfiddle.com link that illustrates the problem. The page you link to just shows an authentication error.

Comment: login required ? To explain use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or something like that...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it it possible using CSS and HTML to allow  elements to overlap, and there are many techniques to do this, however in doing so you will cause the content of those rows to overlap. Unless you actually want to hide you content its not a good space saving technique. It would be better to reduce padding in the rows, and or cells.

Having said that..

```
tr
{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    height:15px;
    top:0px;
}
```

You need to set position to block to stop them acting like table rows, then position either relative or absolute depending on how you need to control them. then set the new top values to match. This style will align all table rows to the top of the table.. Important to note that the cells within the table will no longer be constrained to the  element, this means they'll jump out of the table so will have to be hidden `using overflow:hidden;`

I hope this awnsers your question, but I would urge you to consider a better option than this. If you don't need the content to be displayed setting the  elements `display:none;` Has a better effect and is easier to toggle either inline or as a class.

P.S would be a better example If I had sample code to use.